# https supported in PHP cURL under Apache API, but not under CLI API

Tags: php, cakephp, curl, libcurl

I'm working on a CakePHP-based website. The https protocol is working fine in regular business, but when I try to access data using cURL from the CLI, it gives an error:

```
Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Looking at phpinfo() called from within the CLI and called from a browser, I get two slightly different outputs. PHP version is the same and build dates are within 30 seconds of each other, but the CURL options are very different. Excerpts from the CLI API output:

```
cURL support => enabled
cURL information => 7.40.0
...
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, gopher, http, imap, pop3, rtsp, smtp
```

From the Apache API output:

```
cURL support => enabled
cURL information => 7.19.7
...
protocols tftp, ftp, telnet, dict, ldap, ldaps, http, file, https, ftps
```

The relevant curl.ini files (in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/ and /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/) are identical and contain only "extension=curl.so" (*Edit*: and a search shows only one curl.so on the server); the php.ini files are different, but neither makes reference to curl at all.

How did this come to be, and what's the easiest way to get https working with the CLI API the same way it is with the Apache handler?

Comment: Please try to locate the `php.ini` file loaded in CLI mode `php --ini` and check if the openssl extension is enabled !

Comment: yeah i guess curl needs openssl lib to be loaded to use https, and openssl is disabled in cli - or loaded AFTER curl

Comment: Took another shot at updating the site starting at a day-old backup that worked (no system-level updates; just changes in the app folder) and now it's working just fine. I suspect it was either a change in permissions or a caching issue that triggered it, but that's presumably not the cause. Saving your debugging recommendations for when it inevitably goes bad.